# Why does text disappear after browser page load on a HTC MyTouch 4G?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, browser, htc-mytouch

I'm trying to visit pages like http://irclog.perlgeek.de/crimsonfu/2012-12-01 on my HTC MyTouch 4G running Android 2.2.1 (WebKit 3.1) but I can't read them. The text is visible for a moment until the browser has finished loading and then disappears as demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TriSozFkA-Y

This is very strange behavior to me because the page looks fine on an LG Optimus V also running Android 2.2.1.

On a site I control running the same server software (ilbot), I've found that I can fix the problem by disabling jquery as I reported to the developer at http://irclog.perlgeek.de/ilbot/2012-12-02#i_6204076

This is only a solution for sites I control, however, so I'm wondering what the fix might be. Any clues or reports of being able to reproduce the problem would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the WebKit bundled with HTC sense does not support jQuery properly, which is what is causing this error.

The fix would be to install a non-webkit custom browser, such as Firefox or Opera.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Thanks! I should have mentioned in my question that I had installed Dolphin, but I should have tried a non-WebKit browser, such as Firefox. I just visited http://irclog.perlgeek.de/crimsonfu/2012-12-01 in Firefox and the page renders fine. I upvoted your answer, but I didn't accept it because I'm still wondering what the problem is with the native browser, which uses WebKit 3.1

Comment: Most likely HTC managed to disable full jQuery support in their sense version of the Android WebKit